# Reopen request - Debit Card Risk

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Debit Card Risk](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117080/debit-card-risk/117081)

This was closed with a reason of *Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic because...*

Personally, I don't see this question having anything to do with seeking a product recommendation. It seems like the point of the question is to help the asker understand what happens when a debit card transaction is disputed, which seems (to me) an on-topic question. I have voted to reopen and would like feedback or additional votes if others agree.

Answer (score 2):

I've reopened along with three others. I think as a site we sometimes try to steer clear of very very specific questions about a particular provider, perhaps with either the "product or service recommendations" or "questions about shopping" off-topic reasons in mind.

But I don't think either of them does apply here and it seems like a worthwhile question, although it might be nicer if it was more general rather than being about a specific provider.

Comment: I agree, the fact that a specific merchant was mentioned is a bit of a red herring. It's not important to the nature of the actual question.

Comment: @dwizum - That was the case. I read this as asking about how a particular vendor would behave. In my opinion, the question should have been edited to ask about debit card use, with no reference to any third party.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica even if it asking about the behaviour of a specific vendor, it's not obviously off-topic that I can see. But we probably do have to draw a line somewhere, I'm just not sure where!